# Condition evaluates as True on first condition in all cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have not been able to figure out why jQuery applies the desired new class to body making the first condion always true regarless of different conditions.

The HTML contains these different tags:

```
 <h1 class="entry-title">Intro Audios</h1>
 <h1 class="entry-title">Level 1 Audios</h1>
 <h1 class="entry-title">Level 2 Audios</h1>  
 <h1 class="entry-title">Level 3 Audios</h1>
```

16 pages to be exact contain the h1 tag first aboeve, another 16 contain the h1 tag above and so on.

But no matter what page I visit the added class to the body tag is always "Level-1"

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var level1 = $("h1.entry-title:contains(Level 1)");
var level2 = $("h1.entry-title:contains(Level 2)");
var level3 = $("h1.entry-title:contains(level 3)");

if ( level1)
 {
$(document.body).addClass('level-1');
 } else if (level2 )
 {
$(document.body).addClass('level-2');
 }  else if (level3 )
 {
$(document.body).addClass('level-3');
 } else 
 {
 $(document.body).addClass('intro');

 }
 });

 </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is expected result of `if ( level1)`? Note, `jQuery()` returns an object.

Comment: have you tried adding quotations to your :contains argument?

    var level1 = $("h1.entry-title:contains('Level 1')");

Comment: guest271314  The expected result is a new class added to the body tag. In the case of if (level1) the class added to body tag is 'level-1'. Which does happen but when the other conditions are true 'level-1' class is ALSO added to the body tag.

Comment: Each of the conditions at `if` evaluates  `jQuery()` call. What is purpose of `else..if` statements? Is the `html` created and appended to `document` dynamically?

Comment: This is on a large site of more than 100 pages. These 100 pages are divided in 4 different major categories. I want to add a special class to the body tag depending on the category of each page so that I can give a special style to each one of those pages according to these 4 categories. This is the reason for wanting to add a class to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/djkk8yrg/
Check the console where `level1` and `level2` vars are logged and there is no corresponding html code for level1
They return:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]]
[h1.entry-title, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]]
```

Even though level1 element is not there in the html, it just returns a `prevObject`. Add additional logic to confirm that it's not only prevObject which is returned.

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify that there are docents of pages in this site, a group of them contain the  tags:

      <h1 class="entry-title">Intro Audios</h1>. 

And other groups contain the other HTML tags.

Comment: Anurag Sirha sorry I did not understand how to implement you suggestion.in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do was to be able to add a class to the body tag depending on the condition that a particular wordpress category exists or not. If it exist add the class to body tag so I can stylize each of those pages differently according to new body class.

After trying and testing different answers and codes for a while I found a solution that woks and it is this:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var intro = $( "article" ).hasClass( "category-level-intro" );
 var level_1 = $( "article" ).hasClass( "category-level-1" );
 var level_2 = $( "article" ).hasClass( "category-level-2" );
 var level_3 = $( "article" ).hasClass( "category-level-3" );

 // check to see if the condition is true
 if(intro === true)
  {
  $(document.body).addClass('intro');
  } else if  (level_1 === true)
  {
  $(document.body).addClass('level-1');
  } else if  (level_2 === true)
  {
  $(document.body).addClass('level-2');    
  } else if (level_3 === true )
  {
  $(document.body).addClass('level-3');    
  } else {
  $(document.body).addClass('');  
  }
  });
  </script>
```

Thanks!